# pprint with custom float formats

Tags: python, pprint

I have a nested dictionary structure with tuple keys. Here's what an entry looks like when I pretty-print the dictionary using pprint:

```
...
 ('A', 'B'): {'C': 0.14285714285714285,
              'D': 0.14285714285714285,
              'E': 0.14285714285714285,
              'F': 0.14285714285714285,
              'G': 0.14285714285714285,
              'H': 0.14285714285714285,
              'I': 0.14285714285714285},
...
```

It's pretty nifty, but I'd like to customize it further by cutting down some extra digits from the floats. I was thinking that it'd be possible to achieve by subclassing `pprint.PrettyPrint` but I don't know how that would be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you said, you can achieve this by subclassing `PrettyPrinter` and overwriting the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter.format) method. Note that the output is not only the formatted string, but also some flags.

Once you're at it, you could also generalize this and pass a dictionary with the desired formats for different types into the constructor:

```
class FormatPrinter(pprint.PrettyPrinter):

    def __init__(self, formats):
        super(FormatPrinter, self).__init__()
        self.formats = formats

    def format(self, obj, ctx, maxlvl, lvl):
        if type(obj) in self.formats:
            return self.formats[type(obj)] % obj, 1, 0
        return pprint.PrettyPrinter.format(self, obj, ctx, maxlvl, lvl)
```

Example:

```
>>> d = {('A', 'B'): {'C': 0.14285714285714285,
...                   'D': 0.14285714285714285,
...                   'E': 0.14285714285714285},
...       'C': 255}
...
>>> FormatPrinter({float: "%.2f", int: "%06X"}).pprint(d)
{'C': 0000FF,
 ('A', 'B'): {'C': 0.14,
              'D': 0.14,
              'E': 0.14}}
```

Comment: what about `super(FormatPrinter, self)` instead of `pprint.PrettyPrinter`?

Comment: You probably want to take general formatting functions. So `FormatPrinter({float: '{0:.2f}'.format})`, and have it `return self.formats[type(obj)](obj)`.

Comment: @Artyer Yes, that's a possibility, too. Might be more versatile than just passing the format strings, but also a bit more verbose.

Comment: @Artyer Yeah, that's what I did. Thanks for your additional input. :)

Comment: Thank you for your input.   I use your code with the following changes:   

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    kwargsNext = { key: kwargs[key] for key in kwargs if key != 'formats' }
    super().__init__(**kwargsNext)
    self.formats = kwargs['formats']